# Spark Scala: How to work with each 3 elements of rdd?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

everyone.

I have such problem:

I have very big rdd: billions elements like:

```
Array[((Int, Int), Double)] = Array(((0,0),729.0), ((0,1),169.0), ((0,2),1.0), ((0,3),5.0), ...... ((34,45),34.0), .....)
```

I need to do such operation:

take value of each element by key `(i,j)` and add to it the

```
min(rdd_value[(i-1, j)],rdd_value[(i, j-1)], rdd_value[(i-1, j-1)])
```

How can I do this without using `collect()` as  After `collect()` I have got `Java memory errror` as my rdd is very big.

Thank you very much!

I try to realize this algorithm from python. when time series are rdds.

```
def DTWDistance(s1, s2):
    DTW={}

    for i in range(len(s1)):
        DTW[(i, -1)] = float('inf')
    for i in range(len(s2)):
        DTW[(-1, i)] = float('inf')
    DTW[(-1, -1)] = 0

    for i in range(len(s1)):
        for j in range(len(s2)):
            dist= (s1[i]-s2[j])**2
            DTW[(i, j)] = dist + min(DTW[(i-1, j)],DTW[(i, j-1)], DTW[(i-1, j-1)])

    return sqrt(DTW[len(s1)-1, len(s2)-1])
```

And now I should perform last operation with for loop. The dist is already calculated.

**Example:**

Input (like matrix):

```
4 5 1
7 2 3
9 0 1
```

Rdd looks like

```
rdd.take(10)

Array(((1,1), 4), ((1,2), 5), ((1,3), 1), ((2,1), 7), ((2,2), 2), ((2,3), 3), ((3,1), 9), ((3,2), 0), ((3,3), 1))
```

I want to do this operation

```
rdd_value[(i, j)] = rdd_value[(i, j)] + min(rdd_value[(i-1, j)],rdd_value[(i, j-1)], rdd_value[(i-1, j-1)])
```

For example:

```
((1, 1), 4) = 4 + min(infinity, infinity, 0) = 4 + 0 = 4


4 5 1
7 2 3
9 0 1
```

Then

```
((1, 2), 5) = 5 + min(infinity, 4, infinity) = 5 + 4 = 9


4 9 1
7 2 3
9 0 1
```

Then

....

Then

```
((2, 2), 2) = 2 + min(7, 9, 4) = 2 + 4 = 6


4 9 1
7 6 3
9 0 1
```

Then 
.....

```
((3, 3), 1) = 1 + min(3, 0, 2) = 1 + 0 = 1
```

Comment: Is the 'row' length fixed?

Comment: What do you mean by row length? If you about using only 3 elemets for minimum getting - yes.

Comment: Your data looks like matrix pull out to vector, one row after another. Am I right? If so my question is what is the size of the matrix row?

Comment: Yes, Correct! Now I have the matrix with length of row about 10 000, but in future the length will be bigger and each time different. Also, the number of rows != number of columns in matrix.

Comment: What you are asking is not very clear ! What do you mean by "take value of each element by key and add to it." ? Can you give an sample input and output ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment earlier. Why are you collect your data ? for what purpose ? Collecting your data will collect all the data to your driver thus, if you don't have enough memory, it will give you the error you got.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I do not want to collect my data. I want to calculate by formula and then select only top values.

Comment: But I do not know how to do this operation

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use some variant of dynamic programming. It is not something that can be efficiently and succinctly implemented using RDD API. In particular your Python program executes updates in specific order and we get to (i, j) states of (i - 1, j), (i, j - 1) and (i - 1, j -1) have been already updated in a given iteration. You can easily apply transformation from matrix MI to MJ where MJ(i, j) <- MI(i, j) + min(MI(i - 1, j), MI(i - 1, j - 1),  MI(i, j - 1)) but it is not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

A short answer is that the problem you try to solve cannot be efficiently and concisely expressed using Spark. It doesn't really matter if you choose plain RDDs are distributed matrices.

To understand why you'll have to think about the Spark programming model. A fundamental Spark concept is a graph of dependencies where each RDD depends on one or more parent RDDs. If your problem was defined as follows:

- given an initial matrix *M<sup>0</sup>*
- for *i <- 1..n*

  - find matrix *M<sup>i</sup>* where  *M<sup>i</sup><sub>(m,n)</sub>* = *M<sup>i - 1</sup><sub>(m,n)</sub> + min(M<sup>i - 1</sup><sub>(m-1,n)</sub>,  M<sup>i - 1</sup><sub>(m-1,n-1)</sub>, M<sup>i - 1</sup><sub>(m,n-1)</sub>)*

then it would be trivial to express using Spark API (*pseudocode*):

```
rdd
    .flatMap(lambda ((i, j), v): 
        [((i + 1, j), v), ((i, j + 1), v), ((i + 1, j + 1), v)])
    .reduceByKey(min)
    .union(rdd)
    .reduceByKey(add)
```

Unfortunately you are trying to express dependencies between individual values in the same data structure. Spark aside it a problem which is much harder to parallelize not to mention distribute.

This type of dynamic programming is hard to parallelize because at different points is completely or almost completely  sequential. When you try to compute  for example *M<sup>i</sup><sub>(0,0)</sub>* or *M<sup>i</sup><sub>(m,n)</sub>* there is nothing to parallelize. It is hard to distribute because it can generate complex dependencies between blocks.

There are non trivial ways to handle this in Spark by computing individual blocks and expressing dependencies between these blocks or using iterative algorithms and propagating messages over the explicit graph (GraphX) but this is far from easy to do it right.

At the end of the day there tools which can be much better choice for this type of computations than Spark.

Comment: So, we cannot implement Dynamic Time Wraping in Spark?

Comment: @kinkajou Cannot is probably to strong but even if your derive some approximation designed to leverage distributed processing it is unlikely to be useful and cost effective.